# How can I store UTF8 in MySQL with PHP, sanitize it, echo it with XML and transform it with XSLT?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, utf-8

I am developing a MVC application with PHP that uses XML and XSLT to print the views. It need to be fully UTF-8 supported. I also use MySQL right configured with UTF8. My problem is the next.

I have a `<input type="text"/>` with a value like **àáèéìíòóùú"><'@#~!¡¿?**. This is processed to add it to the database. I use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"])` and then do MySQL a `INSERT`. This will add a slash \ before **"** and **'**.

The MySQL database have a `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8` and `COLLOCATE utf8_spanish_ci`. The table field is a normal `VARCHAR`.

Then I have to print this on a XML that will be transformed with XSLT. I can use PHP on the XML so I echo it with `<?php echo TexUtils::obtainSqlText($value_obtained_from_sql); ?>`. The **obtainSqlText()** function actually returns the same as the $value processed, is waiting for a final structure.

One of the first things that I will need for the selected input is to convert **>** and **<** to `&gt;` and `&lt;` because this will generate problems with start/end tags. This will be done with `<?php htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>`. This will also converts **&** to `&amp;`, **"** to `&quot;` and **'** to `&#039;`. This is a big problem: XSLT starts to fail because it doesn't recognize all HTML special characters.

There is another problem. I've talked about **àáèéìíòóùú"><'@#~!¡¿?** input but I will have some text from a CKEditor `<textarea />` that the value will look like:

```
<p>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">àáèéìíòóùú"><'@#~!¡¿?</a>
</p>
```

How I've to manage this? At first, if I want to print this second value right I will need to use `<xsl:value-of select="value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />`. Will **"><'** print right?

So what I am really looking for is how I need to manage this values and how I've to print. I need to use something if is coming from a `VARCHAR`that doesn't allows HTML  and another if is a `TEXT` (for example) and allows HTML? I will need to use **disable-output-escaping="yes"** everytime?

I also want to know if doing this I am really securing the query from XSS attacks.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This will be done with `<?php htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>`.

Fine.

> This is a big problem: XSLT starts to fail because it doesn't recognize all HTML special characters.

It shouldn't fail on `htmlspecialchars()` output, ever. `&amp;` is a predefined entity in XML and `&#39;` is a character reference which is always allowed. `htmlspecialchars()` should produce XML-compatible output, unlike the usually-a-mistake `htmlentities()`. What is the error you are seeing?

> `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">àáèéìíòóùú"><'@#~!¡¿?</a>`

Urgh, an HTML rich text editor produced that invalid markup? What a dodgy editor.

If you have to allow users to input arbitrary HTML, it's going to need some processing. Unless you really trust those users, you'll need a purifier (to stop them using dangerous scripting elements and XSS-ing each other), and a tidier (to remove malformed markup either due to crap rich-text-editor output or deliberate sabotage). If you intend to put the content directly into XML you will also need it to convert to XHTML output and replace HTML entity references.

A simple way to do this in PHP would be `DOMDocument->loadHTML` followed by a walk of the DOM tree removing all but known-good elements/attributes/URL-schemes, followed by `DOMDocument->saveXML`.

> Will `"><'` print right?

Well, it'll print as in your example, yes. But that's equally invalid as both HTML and XML.

Comment: thank you for you answer. As you say "><' is invalid HTML. How can I write &quot; if is not inside a `<a />` for example and print print " if is inside a `<a />`? How I can managed this? Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to escape `"` to `&quot;` unless it's inside an attribute value delimited by `"`. If you have attribute values with unescaped quotes in, it's not in the general case possible to recover what was meant: eg is `<a b="c" d="e">` an element with two attributes, or one attribute with value `c" d="e`? If this is the sort of markup you have, the component responsible for creating it needs to be fixed. For simpler errors like `<'`, a tidier/purifier should fix them.

Comment: I will talk with the other developer that takes advantage on me about this.

Talking about XSLT part: if for ever string I use `htmlspecialchars()` I will EVER need to use **disable-output-escaping="yes"**, no? I usually used it for printing the possible forms that have HTML but assuming that **àáèéìíòóùú"><'@#~!¡¿?** can be a valid, for example, title for a notice and will need to pass the `htmlspecialchars()` i will need to use the output-escaping. Will have most inputs need, no?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, normally when you're outputting text to HTML that needs one level of HTML-encoding, which can be applied by `htmlspecialchars()` or by XSLT output escaping but not both. You would use both if you wanted to put escaped HTML inside XML, eg for the `<description>` element in an RSS feed. Note that there are problems with using standard XSLT to create HTML: the `html` output method doesn't produce valid HTML output, and the `xhtml` output method doesn't produce HTML-compatible XHTML. It's a bit of a sad mess.